# Angular 5: Conditionally isolate service from component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service which is included in the root module so every component of this module can use the same instance of the service. I have a component called *ComponentX*

**module**

```
providers: [
    BiesbroeckHttpService
],
```

**component**

```
constructor(private biesbroeckHttpService: BiesbroeckHttpService){}
```

But, sometimes, depending on the value of a variable in this *ComponentX*, this same service has to be isolated so it doesn't use the same instance of the service included in the module. This is needed because there are a couple of subscriptions that needs to run parallel.

After searching for hours and numerous tries I still don't know how to do this.

Please help or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not super elegant, but may be a possible solution. You can create an extra service class that extends your `BiesbroeckHttpService`

```
@Injectable()
export class ExtraService extends BiesbroeckHttpService {}
```

Then in your component use `ExtraService` as the token, but use `BiesbroeckHttpService` as the provider defintion.

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: ExtraService,
            useClass: BiesbroeckHttpService
        }
    ]
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(
        private componentService: ExtraService,
        private singletonService: BiesbroeckHttpService
    ){
        // component now has access to both a component instance & the singleton instance
    }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axv9wb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this.

---

One thing to note. If sub components of `MyComponent` need access to `MyComponent`'s instance, you have to inject `ExtraService` instead of `BiesbroeckHttpService`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But if I put this same code in a child component, the child component creates a third isolated instance of the service (right?) that is not accessible by the parent component.
How can the same instance of the isolated service be accessible in child components?

Comment: @Rogier The child component won't create it's own instance if you don't include it in the child's `providers`. so just remove the `providers` array from the child component and inject `ExtraService`

Comment: @Rogier here is a fork of my original [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dm1gku?file=app/hello.component.ts) that shows `hello.component` (the child component) has access to the parent's service instance.

Comment: If I remove the service from the providers array, I get the following error:

ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[IsolatedBiesbroeckHttpService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for IsolatedBiesbroeckHttpService!

Comment: @Rogier hmm, where does your child component exist in your component tree. Is it a child, grand-child, etc.. of the component that provides `ExtraService`?

Comment: It's a direct child

Comment: @Rogier is it possible that component is being using somewhere else that doesn't have access to the service?

Comment: Yes. This child component is also "included" in other components that don't use the `ExtraService`

Comment: @Rogier that is a problem. What is the expected functionality for those components that don't have a parent with `ExtraService`, they use the singleton service?

Comment: Exactly. All components including their childs use the singleton but in a pop-up two components are re-used but have to use an isolated service. If this isn't possible, I'd be forced to create a special pop-up component. I rather not since the content and functionality is the same as the component outside of the pop-up.

Answer (score -2):

I would just make another service for the isolated case and use a if statement on the actual component to decided which service to use.

Comment: It works but you would have to duplicate the entire code, there is maybe a better solution

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The service is pretty complex and under continuous development so this would be the last option.